# Can I operate a 12vdc valve using a capacitor and AA batteries?

Tags: batteries, capacitor

First, I need to specify I'm very noob, so maybe in my situation a vague awnser is better than something very specific, I don't know.

I want to make an airbow (airgun that shoots arrows) like the one Joerg Sprave made on his YouTube channel. Except, he powered it with a 12 dc battery, whitch is very straight-forward, but also quite expensive and heavy, compared to AA or maybe higher batteries, boosted with a capacitor. The thing is I know nothing of what to expect about the output of the capacitor. I know it can be quite high, because once I made fun of shocking myself with one made for a flash, with friends, and it gave quite a jolt. Anyway.

I want to have a switch button, once pressed it would give power to the valve just long enough to deliver the compressed air and shoot the arrow, so it doesnt need long, once the arrow it shot, any excess air is futile. If it's simple to install, I would like a LED to signal when the valve/gun is ready to fire, but it's optional.

I can go a bit with trial and error, but I wouldn't fry my valve in the process since it's the most expensive part of the project yet. I dont mind a schematic for the circuit if you can provide, but (ok I know I sound very helpless) if there was at least some clear note (e.g.: your valve, power source:aa battery), it would help me a lot to understand the big picture. I'm sure I can, but the last time I worked with electronics was more than 20 years ago, and I'm 37.

I hope my question is not too boring or too easy or too vague, thanks for any help.

Comment: have you estimated the energy drawn?  can you afford to lose power?

Answer (score 3):

8 AA in series will produce 12V. It should trigger the air valve at probably 9V (A 9V battery has a high ESR and a low capacity and current delivering power, so stick to AA or C cells for multiple triggering). Unless the valve is incredibly power hungry.

The capacitor is to make it a bit easier on the batteries.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this will make it very much easier to build, though not like my fantasy-world dream build I imagined :)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to do is find how much current the valve needs, and for how long.  Then you can calculate what size capacitor can deliver that current for that time, and not drop too much voltage in the process.

Once you have that, you have to decide how to charge up the capacitor.  You could put enough batteries in series to get 12 V, and then just connect the capacitor across them.  Since the capacitor by itself can operate the solenoid, you don't need a battery with very low internal resistance, like a car battery.

Since the equivalent resistance of the voltage source charging the cap doesn't matter, you can use just a few cells or even a single cell and a boost converter.  This is exactly what goes on in the camera flash you mentioned.  The boost converter takes the low voltage from the battery to make high voltage, and a cap gets charged with that high voltage.  This can take a few seconds because the energy required to activate the solenoid is provided by the battery slowly, stored in the cap, then released from the cap suddenly.

Boosting a single 3-4 V rechargeable lithium cell to 12 V isn't hard.  The time you have to wait for the cap to charge up depends on the size of the cap, and the current the boost converter can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If the air valve operates on 12 volts, you just need a 12 volt battery.  The battery must be large enough (enough stored energy and current capability) to supply the current the valve requires.

I'm guessing the battery Joerg Sprave used was a lead-acid car battery (but I haven't searched for his YouTube video).  Eight AA or C cells in series will produce 12 volts and may produce enough current to operate the valve (but a datasheet for the valve would help to confirm this).

A capacitor will only charge to the voltage of its charging source - if you connect the capacitor across a 12 volt battery, it will only charge up to 12 volts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a misconception about capacitors then, this is what I thought by researching but I wanted to be sure, since every link I found had very advanced math I knew nothing about. For the video, i suggest it a lot, you will understand my interest I'm sure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fs3uEBw2u1Y

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use several batteries you can use a step-up switching regulator to generate 12V from lower voltages.

Comment: This really depends on the current requirements.